# CakePHP - Sanitize::clean leaving &amp and \n

Tags: cakephp, sanitization

I'm getting a little confused with what exactly cakePHPs Sanitize::clean() method should do. Currently when I'm adding a record I'm doing this:

```
$this->request->data = Sanitize::clean($this->request->data, array('encode' => true, 'remove_html' => true));
```

However, this still leaves & and \n in my database when they use & and press enter in a textarea. How can I stop this? I thought remove_html => true would have done this?

Do I need to go as far as doing a str_replace()

Also some of the records with the \n 's in them have hundreds of trailing backslashes meaning the break any views they are displayed on.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

**Update as per Nunsers answer**

I've now added the following after the clean:

```
foreach ($this->request->data['Expense'] as &$expense) {
    $expense['detail'] = Sanitize::stripWhitespace($expense['detail']);         
}
unset($expense);
```

However, it does remove whitespace but still leaves lots of `\n\n\n\n\n\`

Heres a debug of $this->request->data:

```
array(
    'submit' => 'Save',
    'Expense' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'date' => array(
                'day' => '27',
                'month' => '06',
                'year' => '2013'
            ),
            'sitename' => 'test',
            'detail' => 'test test\n\ntest\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n',
            'ExpenseCode' => array(
                'ExpenseCode' => '1'
            ),
            'billable' => '1',
            'amount' => '1',
            'miles' => '',
            'total' => '1',
            'billable_mileage' => '',
            'recorded_global_mileage_rate' => '0.4'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'date' => array(
                'day' => '27',
                'month' => '06',
                'year' => '2013'
            ),
            'sitename' => 'test',
            'detail' => '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\ntest',
            'ExpenseCode' => array(
                'ExpenseCode' => '4'
            ),
            'billable' => '1',
            'amount' => '10',
            'miles' => '',
            'total' => '10',
            'billable_mileage' => '',
            'recorded_global_mileage_rate' => '0.4'
        )
    ),
    'CashFloat' => array(
        'amount' => ''
    ),
    'ExpenseClaim' => array(
        'user_id' => '3',
        'claim_status_id' => '1'
    )
)
```

I'd like to strip thouse \n's out really as I dont want them break views.

**More results**

Even when I cut out the cake function and use its code directly inline via :

```
$expense['detail'] = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/u', ' ', preg_replace('/[\n\r\t]+/', '', $expense['detail']));
```

I still get the same (debug($expense['detail']) from the loop:

```
'test 10 spaces before this then pressing enter lots \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'
```

I've also tried just a basic trim() which didnt work at all.

**Working solution (apart from the &)**

This will remove any number of

```
\n
```

from the string

```
foreach ($this->request->data['Expense'] as &$expense) {

    $expense['detail'] = str_replace("\\n", ' ', $expense['detail']);
    $expense['detail'] = Sanitize::stripWhitespace($expense['detail']);             
}
// Unset referance var from above loop
unset($expense);
```

**Decided to keep the &**

And just use `html_entity_decode()` when echoing it out in a view

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Sanitize.html#_clean), the `clean` method does not do what you want.

First, for the `\n` characters, you should call another Sanitize function. `Sanitize::clean()` has a `carriage` option, but that only removes the `\r` characters. So, after (or before) calling the `clean` method, call [stripWhitespaces](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-Sanitize.html#124-132). Unfortunately, this functions only receives a string, so you need to call it in a loop (or if you know the string you want to sanitize, use it for just that).

```
$cleanOfSpacesString = Sanitize::stripWhitespace($dirtyString);
```

That function removes this characters: `\r`, `\n` and `\t`, and replace 2 or more spaces with just one.

And for `&`, the docs says that `remove_html` removes html tags and also does a `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, $defaultCharset, true)` to the string. So if that `htmlentities` is not working for you, you'll have to use another function not incuded in the `Sanitize` class.

If you think this behaviour is something you want to have inside the helper, extend the Sanitize helper to include `stripWhiteSpaces` inside the `clean` function and to also replace the `htmlentities` function with something that works for you. If it's just for this case, add those functions in the controller, after calling `Sanitize::clean`

---

**Update as per Jason's update to my answer**

I found it weird that the `stripWhitespaces` function didn't work as you wanted. And here is the explanation of why I think it didn't.

You want to remove `\n` from a string like this

```
'test test\n\ntest\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'
```

and the preg_replace inside stripWhitespaces is this

```
preg_replace('/[\n\r\t]+/', '', $str)
```

That regex *will* remove newlines, returns and tabs, *but* on a string like this

```
'test test

test

' //and a lot more newlines
```

So the difference here is that you're passing the newlines (maybe the tabs and returns also, I don't know) as *strings*, real`\`+`n`, and so, the `preg_replace` cake does is not useful for you. I know you found a solution for that (I recommend you add the tab and return match also in there), but I wanted to clarify *why* cake's function didn't work in case someone else has a similar problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - it now strips the whitespace but leaves the \n's I've updated my question with more details - would you mind taking a look? Thanks

Comment: Should also note I'm running 2.2.1 - http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/source-class-Sanitize.html#_stripWhitespace

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I think is the reason for your `\n` been ignored :)